# Cannot rebuild ASP.NET Web Applicaiton missing solution file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am taking over an ASP.NET Web Application using C# and all the code (including C# source) was given to me without the solution file (something.sln) so whenever opening the Web Application in Visual Studio 2017 I have to open by "Folder..." instead of by "Project/Solution...". Once open, I am able to make the necessary changes to the code behind files such as Default.aspx.cs or somethingElse.aspx.cs, but when I try to test the code changes by going to Run > Start Without Debugging, I couldn't find the Run menu option; I see the Build Solution button but it's disabled (greyed out).

Every time I try navigating directly to my site at http://dev.mydomain.com. The code changes I made did not get compiled neither.

So how do I get the Run or Build menu option enabled?

Comment: Isn't there a .csproj file? If it was a properly set up project there ought to be one of those, and you can open that in visual studio without a solution file

Comment: Of course the obvious way to correct this issue would be to create a new solution (and new project if necessary) and copy the code files into it

Comment: There is not .csproj file neither, I forgot to mention. And you said "obvious way to correct this issue would be to create a new solution (and new project if necessary) and copy the code files into it", how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You already know how to create a new project in visual studio I hope??

Comment: Yes, can you list all the steps including copying the code files into it .

Comment: I pretty much just did list all the main steps: create the project (and solution file with it if you wish). Then copy your code files to the folder newly created. Then tell VS to include them in your project.

Comment: How do i mark your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: The above is just a comment so you can't mark it. I have now written it up as a proper answer below, which you can "accept" by clicking on the tick mark next to it, so it turns green. You can also give up/downvotes as appropriate too. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to correct this issue is probably to create a new, empty ASP.NET WebForms project (and a new solution file as well if necessary) and copy your code files into it. You can then tell Visual Studio to "include" those files in the project.

You may (or may not) need to make the odd other minor adjustment too but those basic steps should get you started.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly and it's working now. But all the assembly references are missing, so I had to add them one by one and I'm done with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related, but adding the sln file to the git ignore removed its visibility from VisualStudio. I had to open the project csproj file in VisualStudio.

THen on close, the prompt was asking me to save a new SLN file with the same solution name i was looking for. I was then able to go to the directory with the original solution in it, and then I was able to open it again in Visual Studio.
For all those who come to this post in the future, I would check your gitignore files and see if they ignored the sln file.